# Laravel and Xdebug - I can't debug because of Fatal error: Can't find Controller class that all controllers extend it

Tags: php, laravel, debugging, xdebug

So I managed to configure Xdebug (2.4.0) for PHP 7 (7.0.4). However I can't use it in my Laravel project. I am trying to debug a block of code inside my CartController. However it says that there is an error because it can't find the Controller that my CartController extends. This is what I get in my PhpStorm console:

> C:\xampp\php\php.exe -dxdebug.remote_enable=1 -dxdebug.remote_mode=req
>   -dxdebug.remote_port=9000 -dxdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1 C:\Users\Nikolay\Dropbox\store\app\Http\Controllers\CartController.php
>   PHP Fatal error:  Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Controller' not found in
>   C:\Users\Nikolay\Dropbox\store\app\Http\Controllers\CartController.php
>   on line 14 PHP Stack trace: PHP   1. {main}()
>   C:\Users\Nikolay\Dropbox\store\app\Http\Controllers\CartController.php:0
>
> Fatal error: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Controller' not found in
>   C:\Users\Nikolay\Dropbox\store\app\Http\Controllers\CartController.php
>   on line 14
>
> Call Stack:
>       2.1491     376944   1. {main}() C:\Users\Nikolay\Dropbox\store\app\Http\Controllers\CartController.php:0
>
> Process finished with exit code 255

There is no problem in the application itself when I run it on a server. How can I fix that and why does it occur?

Edit - 28/05/2016 - Here is the CartController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Cart;
use App\CartItem;
use App\Product;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

class CartController extends Controller
{
    public function showCart() {...}

    public function addItem(Request $request, $product_id) {...}

    public function deleteItem($product_id, $size) {...}

    public function showCheckout() {...}

    private function calculateTotalPrice() {...}
}
```

Comment: You should really paste the relevant class code here, as well as the class file name. Check if the CAPS match between the two.

Comment: I updated my question but I get the same exact error with every controller I try to debug.

Comment: Have you checked the `Controller.php` file exists in `C:\Users\Nikolay\Dropbox\store\app\Http\Controllers`? If so, is the namespace of that class `namespace App\Http\Controllers;`? And is the class named `Controller`?

Comment: Yes it is the same namespace. Controller exists. The application works but the debugger doesn't.

Comment: The only logical explanation for the issue is that the debugger doesn't load the classes. As you know, Laravel uses Composer with two purposes: package manager and autoloader. So, if the application works and the debugger doens't, that means the debugger is unable to locate / load the composer file with the class names. Check [this link](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/controller-class-not-found-during-debug-in-phpstorm) for a situation similar to yours. Also check the settings of the debugger and verify if you can point to the autoload file (`/vendor/autoload.php`)

Answer (score 5):

I'm probably mistaken ... but it almost sounds like you're trying to debug just the controller without going through bootstrapping/routing etc?

You application is working one the server because all of the bootstrapping, instantiation, dependency injection etc. is done.

To debug the application flow you could debug `public/index.php` with breakpoints in your controller methods and either manually set/override `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` with the route you want to debug in index.php before ... or you install the xdebug browser extension, start the debug listener in PHPStorm and the visit your route in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with VsCode.
In the root of the Laravel project, I created a .vscode folder. Inside this new folder I created a launch.json file
Containing the following content:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Listen for XDebug",
      "type": "php",
      "request": "launch",
      "port": 9000,
      "pathMappings": {
        "/var/www/html": "${workspaceFolder}/"
      },
      "xdebugSettings": {
        "max_data": -1,
        "show_hidden": 1,
        "max_children": 100,
        "max_depth": 5
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please add supporting details to your answer to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, using any IDE editor (either using netbeans or VS code). The problem was I started debugging from files other than main index.php (auto loader file). When I started from index.php file everything started to work. I would anyway explain in stepwise how to correct

1. Locate the proper php.ini file. Create a info.php file in /var/www/html/ and write

then browse this file in browser and locate php.ini. Also locate which xdebug version your system have from there.

2. Configure first the xdebug (in this php.ini file).       There are major 2 (as of the time of writing) xdebug versions.
   a. XDebug 2
   b. XDebug 3

Create an xdebug section in the very last of this php.ini file.

```
[xdebug]
```

3. XDebug 2 had those setting

   zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/20170718/xdebug.so
   xdebug.default_enable=1
   xdebug.remote_enable=on
   xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
   xdebug.remote_host=localhost
   xdebug.remote_port=9000

change the path to xdebug which you had. Find xdebug using this command

```
find /usr/lib/php -iname xdebug.so
```

if you had multiple version of php installed you would get more than one xdebug. To know which one you would be using is then just removing and installing xdebug and in which folder it disappear and reappears that xdebug is you need. e.g. to know what version php7.4 is using remove php7.4-xdebug module and then install it; using

```
sudo apt remove php7.4-xdebug
```

and then install it again using

```
sudo apt install php7.4-xdebug
```

while Xdebug 3 had those setting instead

```
 zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/20190902/xdebug.so
 xdebug.mode=debug
 xdebug.client_host=localhost
 xdebug.remote_port=9003
```

some setting is the same in both versions

```
 xdebug.profiler_output_dir=/tmp
 xdebug.profiler_output_name=cachegrind.out.%p
 xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger=1
 xdebug.profiler_enable=0
 xdebug.remote_autostart=1
 xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
```

Change xdebug.idekey to vsc for VS code or phpstorm etc for your ide

4. start your ide and open your laravel project. e.g. in VScode open folder and selecting your project folder
5. open your main index.php file in public folder

and start debugging